# How did people make complex programs in C before the Internet and Google?

Tags: c

So I decided to look up some source code for a simple text editor in C, and it required me to use a header called conio.h. This got me thinking, how did people write programs like text editors or web browsers before you could google up headers and other libraries?

Comment: Reading text on a screen was preceded by reading text in a book.

Answer (score 7):

It was as always: you program by writing code and test it, not googling around for inspiration.

This being said, you always needed some prime information. the first source was k&r. Then you had some primer manuals like the "the c primer". Then the next source was your compiler's library reference manual (paper). Back in 1985 there were not so many free libraries. You had to purchase some, and again rely on tutorial and library reference and try it yourself until it works.

Later you also had some nice magazines such as Dr.Dobbs, Byte, the C Journal and the C User's Journal (both of which ended to merge). These had reports about cool tools or libraries to purchase, programming techniques with source code, etc.

The main difference was that you had to search much more by yourself (try and error), and share experience with peers. And if you could afford a modem, you could enjoy the small community of a BBS forum hosted by some volonteer.

And programming then was as fun as programming today, even if the productivity was lower.

Comment: Any tips on beginners programs I could write, assuming I just finished reading Learn-C.org? Anything even remotely graphical? Or should I stick to writing terminal programs? If so, what kind? I am completely clueless as to what I can do with "function pointers"

Comment: Just writing code and testing it is a truly tremendously stupid idea in a language with so much undefined behaviour. Just because your tests appear to work doesn't mean it actually does...

Comment: @DeadMG believe it or not: but before having all these undefined behaviours (c89) there was only k&r and a lot of ambiguity. This is why compiler manual was part of source.  And yes: some things worked on one compiler and not on the other because your assumptions were implementation dependent. It may sound stupid to you, but in 1984 when i learned c there was no other choice.

Comment: @TheLastSaneStudentInAnIn imho you have to get a good langage understanding first. If you go graphic, you have to digest as well event based programming and lots of library (or os) dependent knowledge. Learning programming is like climbing stairs: one step at a time will bring you to the top. Of course you can jump several stairs at once, but the higher the jumps, the greater the risks of missing the step ;-)

Comment: @Christophe: That does *not* make it a remotely good idea.

Comment: @Christophe, then what would you suggest is my next step after reading the C books for beginners?

Comment: @TheLastSaneStudentInAnIn try to write a console app. Start with some command line utilities. Then a little game (gomoku, othello, power 4,...) but in a keyboard entry-display-computer-display modus. Then improve it using cursor control (e.g. Using Ncurse library or win console api). Then follow a gui tutorial. Then rework your game code to give it a gui interface. Then you're ready with a deeper understanding to start your next challenge. There are surely plenty of other ways.

Comment: @TheLastSaneStudentInAnIn: A simple database app like a contact list will hit most of the major points in software development - I/O, memory management, data structures, etc.  Start with a simple command-line interface.  If you want to get adventurous and do some network programming, write a simple email or NNTP client (again, with a simple CLI).

Comment: Kids these days. Study assembly language for the processor of your choice (book in hand, experiment, trial, failure, correction), and proceed from there. Without spending some time with assembler, you won't really understand what your higher level languages are actually doing. The early C compilers just spit out assembler which you then had to deal with. Every generation of programming tools simply adds an additional layer of convenience, which you'll best appreciate by doing things inconveniently.

Answer (score 2):

> how did people write programs like text editors or web browsers before you could google up headers and other libraries?

Back in the Jurassic ('60s through the early '70s), everyone used the hardcopy programming manuals and development tools that came with the system.  There weren't a lot of third-party tools or libraries to choose from, mainly because there were almost no open standards.

Sometime in the Cretacous (late '70s to early '80s) people started putting RFCs, manuals, and code on Usenet, but you had to know where to look.

By the late Cretacous (late '80s) you could use tools like Archie and Gopher to efficiently search for manuals and code online.

Mosiac was the KT impact.  That's what signaled the sea change towards network-centric applications and programming.

Remember that hardware capability has to evolve before people can take advantage of it in software.  It wasn't *that* long ago that 256K was a lot of very expensive memory, and everyone had strict quotas on disk space.  My school had a couple of hardcopy terminals still lying around.  There's a constant feedback between programmers pushing the hardware and hardware manufacturers offering new features.

Answer (score -4):

The same way they shared information on any other matter - by writing books, attending talks, formal training, manufacturer's manuals, that sort of thing.

Just to add to this, conio.h is a DOS header from about 1985, and using that in code today is an absolute joke. So is C, for that matter. The information you've found online is of laughably low quality. Not exactly a resounding win for the Google era. You might find useful a question about "How do I find information that isn't total garbage?".

Comment: Books, books, more books. The bookshelves of programmers were full of books.

Comment: Why is C such a laughable language, and is there anything wrong with using old headers?

Comment: C is a laughable language because it basically offers no features of use. The only thing C is still good for is chips so cheap, small, or low-power they can't support any remotely modern programming techniques. As for using old headers, they can be unsupported, don't offer things you would actually need, etc. But most problematically, they do not adhere to programming practices worth using and can force you to write your own code in a similarly godawful way.

Comment: @DeadMG: A lot of software is still written in C also for non cheap processors, e.g. the Linux kernel.

Comment: @Giorgio while true, Linux is not written in Standard C — instead in GNU C.

Comment: The processor mode they're writing for effectively behaves the same, so I don't really see the difference.

Comment: Come on man. You've been around long enough to know that this isn't an acceptable answer. *Be Nice.*

Comment: By the way, conio.h despite being aging and certainly not the way to go, should not be a showstopper for those who want to refresh some legacy code. There are plenty of qustions/answers on SO on how to replace the conio functions  such as kbhit() or gotoxy() and alike.

Comment: The language of choice for communications engineering is still C or C++. Some people have moved on to C++, but many still use plain C. No other language has the same features (possibility of extremely high performance, possibility of replacing malloc() with a more efficient allocator, guaranteed low delay due to not having garbage collection, access to new processor-specific instructions to improve performance, ...). Firewalls? They use C. Intrusion prevention/detection systems? C. Mobile network equipment? C. Operating system kernels? C. Even new projects such as Open vSwitch use C.